# ZF2 Navigation: How to show some pages ONLY in breadcrumb navigation

Tags: php, zend-framework, navigation, zend-framework2, breadcrumbs

In Zend Framework 2 I use ZendNavigation for the main navigation and the breadcrumb-navigation. I want the Breadcrumb-Navigation to show on every page, but I do not want every page to appear in the main navigation.

So in other words I want some pages to show **ONLY** in breadcrumb navigation.

Is there any way to achieve this? Maybe an option that can be set in the navigation-array? Or do I need to create two different navigations and use one as main navigation and the other as breadcrumb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

It doesn't really make sense to duplicate the 'pages' configuration as you can instruct the view helper to render what you need. So you can use the **same** navigation container to render different menus (e.g. breadcrumb vs main navigation).

You can do this by either [using the provided breadcrumb methods](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.navigation.view.helper.breadcrumbs.html#customize-output) such as `setMaxDepth()` or `setMinDepth()`. Alternatively, for more flexibility, use a view partial as I explained bellow.

In each case you are simply filtering down the complete container into the seletion you want to render.

---

You can use a [view partial to render the breadcrumbs](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.navigation.view.helper.breadcrumbs.html#rendering-using-a-partial-view-script).

> This method will find the deepest active page and pass an array of pages that leads to the active page to the partial view script.

The example in the attached link uses `array_map` to render the contents of `$this->pages`, however you can achieve the same result with a loop.

```
foreach($this->pages as $page) {
  printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $page->getHref(), $page->getLabel());
}
```

Keep in mind however you will now need to check the accessibility of the page manually for the current user if you are using the ACL - This can be done using the [methods available for MVC or URL pages](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.navigation.pages.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that was not exactly my question. My breadcrumb-Navigation is rendering and working. 

I don't know how to display some pages ONLY in breadcrumb navigation and others ONLY in main navigation. Right now ALL my pages display in BOTH navigations.
For example: I want my main menu to only contain page "Admin", no subpages. But in my breadcrumb-navigation I need to specify all the subpages, like "Admin -> Users" etc.

Comment: I was hoping for a more convenient solution, but this is probably the best way to handle this. Thanks for your help!